# django migrate error nodename nor servname provided, or not known name 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migrate

I'm using django 1.7.6, python 2.7.10, postgres 9.5.3 on a mac running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Here are my database settings in settings.py.  The important values are

```
RDS_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
RDS_PORT=5432

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3' if 'test' in sys.argv else 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': RDS_DB_NAME,
        'USER': RDS_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': RDS_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': RDS_HOSTNAME,
        'PORT': RDS_PORT,
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False
    }
}
```

I manually created the database and DB role and this matches settings on a different box.

When I run `python manage.py migrate` I get the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 183, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.get_table_list(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 167, in cursor
    cursor = utils.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 138, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 130, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known name "127.0.0.1
```

I know this worked before so it is probably something simple.  I can run `python manage.py test` but most tests fail.  I tried uninstalling then reinstalling all packages used.  I've searched the web for 1.5 days for a solution.  Not sure what to try next.  Thanks

Comment: I get the same error when executing python `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001`

Comment: Please close this question.  I think it is related to Mac firewalls but still haven't gotten this to work from the command line.  Works from Pycharm if I allow access.